# C (time.h) clock_t = clock() producing wrong duration

Tags: c, time, raspberry-pi

Some example code:

```
clock_t clock_start = clock();

for( ... ) { ... do stuff ... }

clock_t clock_stop = clock();

double duration = 1000.0 * (clock_stop - clock_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("time: %f ms\n", duration);
```

When I ran this code it produced an output of:

```
time: 4756.869000 ms
```

This is clearly wrong. I estimate the actual time taken is about 10 seconds, and verified this via a stop watch.

There appears to be a factor of about 2 - 3 missing.

Is it possible that `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is defined as something nonsensical on my system? (I am using a Raspberry Pi 3, with Raspberry Pi OS.) Is there any way to check this? Or is it more likely that something else is the cause of the issue.

I am aware of alternative methods of measuring time on posix systems. I will implement some tests with one of those as a possible alternative, regardless.

Comment: "Some example code:" please turn it into a [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch A MWE is clearly irrelevant here, as well as being impossible or impractical to provide.

Answer (score 4):

> The `clock()` function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program.

It says "processor time", *not* the amount of time that a stopwatch would say. If you want to measure the amount of time passing in the real world, you simply need to use one of those other functions.

Comment: Yep, just managed to figure this out from some more tests - the program is spending about 50% of time which is logged by clock() and the rest I assume are system calls and that sort of thing - which makes sense as it interacts with the kernel to access some devices.